# How to do this integral analytically?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate the following integral analytically $$f(x,y)=\int_{\Omega }d^2ke^{i(xk_x+yk_y)}$$, where the region $\Omega=\left \{ (k_x,k_y):k_x^2+k_y^2\leq K^2 \right \}$ with radius $K>0$.

What's the exact form of $f(x,y)$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use polar coordinates, and the fact that $x k_x+y k_y = r \rho \cos{(\theta-\phi)}$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\rho=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}$.  We therefore get

$$f(x,y) = \int_0^K d\rho \, \rho \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i r \rho \cos{(\theta-\phi)}}$$

The inner integral is a Bessel function, so we get

$$f(x,y) = 2 \pi \int_0^K d\rho\, \rho \, J_0(r \rho) = \frac{2 \pi}{r^2} \int_0^{K r} du \, u\, J_0(u) = 2 \pi K^2 \frac{J_1(K r)}{K r}$$