# How to analyze the asymptotic properties of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, asymptotics, exponential-function, singularity-theory

Let the function $$f(\mathbf{r})=\int_{\Omega }e^{i\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}}d^2\mathbf{k}$$, where $\mathbf{k} ,\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is some *finite* region with a boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Without knowing the analytical form of $f(\mathbf{r})$, how do we analyze the asymptotic behaviour of $f(\mathbf{r})$ at large distance $\left | \mathbf{r} \right |\rightarrow \infty $? Does it behave like $f(\mathbf{r})\sim e^{-\left | \mathbf{r} \right |/L}$ or $f(\mathbf{r})\sim \left | \mathbf{r} \right |^{-a}$ at large distance, with $L$ the characteristic length and $a$ some positive number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an aswer, but consider as an example that the region is a unit square: then we have the (factorizable) Fourier transform of a rect function, which is a sinc, and the tails are bounded by $1/r$

Comment: @ leonbloy Good example. Another example is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527512/how-to-do-this-integral-analytically , and the function $f(\mathbf{r})$ behaves like $r^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ at large distance. So the asymptotic behaviour depends on the geometry of the region $\Omega $, I want to know in general, how we we analyze the large distance asymptotic behaviour without knowing the explicit form of $f(\mathbf{r})$?

Comment: Oscillating $\large\sim{\rm e}^{{\rm i}qr}$ where $q \sim 1/L$.

Comment: @ Felix Marin No, the amplitude decays as power law.